# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 on Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, codesign

I'm trying to build for App Store but I got the error `Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1`. I tried to clean DerivedData, restart computer, revoke keys and create new one. I had updated my mac to catalina and Xcode 11, before the upgrade it was working.

```
/Users/digistarts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glehwjejufujqwblxzreggowpgvb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: replacing existing signature
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: Daniel Santana (85UL9U2WVT)"
/Users/digistarts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glehwjejufujqwblxzreggowpgvb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you export and import to and from the old and new Macs the apple profile and certs in Xcode first?

Comment: Yes @RichardBarber, but a found the erro and solution and a I'll post, thanks for reply for help anyone

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In **Keychain Access**... The solution was right clicking on **Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority** and select **Get Info**. In the Image bellow, I've change **When using this certificate** to **Use System Defaults** and the system asked me to put password. Now it's working \o/

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly, I had the exact same issue and your solution resoled mine as well. Just wonder how did you understood the problem ? where did you found out about that "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations..." certificate ? Thanks !

Comment: I had followed another suggestion in SO to set it as Always Allow, I'm so glad now I'm using fastlane and letting it take care of all of this non-sense for me

Comment: This fixed also my Xcode 13 RANDOM issues with this, when archiving. I mean wtf Apple, I never had problems with this until Xcode 13.

Comment: In My case, I have multiple same certificates with different expiry dates in my keychain access. I kept the one and removed remaining certificates. And restated the Xcode, clean build and rebuild works fine.

Comment: Had a similar issue using the `codesign` utility that this resolved. Tried so many things, just needed to set Trust correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In case it'll be helpful for someone else - I had the same problem, which only was reproduced with no internet connection, and as fast as I connect back - error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

My project xamarin forms.
I had such a problem after renewing the certificate, it turned out **at the end of the build on the Mac it asks for the user's password** when checking the certificate.